# Count rows of right table when joinning two tables using SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a question about SQL Query. Let me do the example to illustration my issue:
I have two tables like this:

**Roles Table**

```
ID                    Role                        Role Description
1                     Administrator               Someone in administrator board
2                     User                        Someone who has an account
3                     Guess                       Someone who just view the website
```

**Users Table**

```
ID                  Username                 RoleID
1                    trind08                      1
2                    trind09                      1
3                    trind10                      1
4                    kimchi                       2
5                    linhchi                      2
6                    thanh01                      2
7                    thanh02                      3
8                    kiemanh                      3
9                    liemanh                      3
```

My issue is I want to view all roles and count the user who resolve to them.

**Result table** after running the query might look like this:

```
ID                Role                            Role Description                                Cound of User
1                 Administrator                   Someone in administrator board                  3
2                 User                            Someone who has an account                      3
3                 Guess                           Someone who just view the website               3
```

My first try to create a SQL Query like this:

```
select rol.*, usrCout as 'Count of User' from Roles rol
left join (select count(*) from Users where RoleID == rol.ID) usrCout;
```

But my query run unsuccessfully and I can't get the result I want. Please help me for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
ID
,ROLE
,Role Description
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users where RoleID = rol.ID) AS UserCount
FROM Roles rol
```

Comment: It ran very good. I got the result firmly. There is a misspell in your query at '==' instead of '=' but I changed it a little bit and the job is done. Thank too much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

`Select count(*) as 'Count of User', r.RoleID, Role, Role Description   from role r, Users u where u.RoleId = r.Id group by r.RoleID,Role, Role Description;`

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3f49/1)

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, your query just count all user in table user, but not the amount of users who resolve to specific role.

Comment: @TriNguyenDung It counts number of users for each role. Try the fiddle

Comment: It ran very good. I got a correct result. Your query is very fit my issue. Thank too much for your help.